# What does "Higher Precedence" mean?

Tags: java, boolean-operations

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) the precedence level of AND is higher than OR.

I was wondering, if i have a clause stated as ***a || b && c***

How it should be computed first? `(a||b) or (b && c)?`

Comment: why don't you try it? think OR as + and AND as *

Comment: It seems to me that you started with the answer here. What part of 'the precedence level of AND is higher than OR' didn't you understand?

Comment: It's given in wiki and you are still wondering...

Comment: i asked to get a confirmation to check if i had in mind was right

Comment: Please do not EVER rely on the precedence of `&&` related to `||`. **ALWAYS** use parentheses for the sake of readability!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` has a higher precedence over `OR` in JAVA.  So `(b && c)` should be computed before `(a||b)` in expression `a || b && c`

Check this for complete list:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Snapshot taken from the link:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Due to precedence, it evaluates as

```
(a || ( b && c))
```

And if you add parentheses (manually), parentheses are evaluated before anything else and  changes everything.

if you write

```
   ((a || b) && c)
```

That matters!

Answer (score 2):

You should just try it out in a test script, but if the wiki says AND has higher precedence then I would assume `b&&c` is called first.

Answer (score 2):

Because AND has a higher order precendence, (b && c) would be evaluated first, then the result of that would be ORed with a. In other words this is equivalent to a || (b && c)

Answer (score 0):

This has very straight forward answer, it evaluate b&&c first simply because **AND** operation has higher precedence in the order than **OR** operation.

Let me explain with a more known example about precedence,

Let's take 5+2*2

We all know 2*2 is the first to evaluate and then the 5 will be added to the 4(2*2). Likewise there is order of evaluation in logic's too and that's a standard you have to follow. :)